# grails tomcat -- are user errors isolated

Tags: grails

If I have a grails app deployed in Tomcat with 100 users interacting with the site, and one user executes some code that results in an unrecoverable error / stacktrace, are the other 99 users totally isolated from that error?  I'm thinking that should be the case with the underlying threading model, but I wanted to confirm.

Thanks

Comment: can you explain your problem more precisely? which action does the user perform? post the stacktrace ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where the error happens. If it's something that is localized to the currently executing thread, then other users are not affected. You can, however, create something that will affect all users on the site - an extreme example being a call to *System.exit()* without a SecurityManager running.

So yes, Grails (or more precisely Tomcat or other application server) will run a thread for each separate request so throwing an exception will only be local to the thread where it gets thrown.

Comment: Thanks Lauri -- can you tell me the best way to see an error that occurs for a given a User.  In ColdFusion, there is support to easily send an email capturing the error, but I could also look at a log file if it one can limit it to these kinds of errors (vs tons of regular activity).